# Works fine in sqlite bus as I changed to postgresql I get ProgrammingError at / relation "mainapp_post" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I recently switched to postgresql, I finally didn't get any error in terminal that I thought every thing was set. But in browser, I get this error again;

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "main_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."main_post"."image", "main_post"."thumbnail" FROM "main_post...
```

It was working fine in sqlite3, not sure why I get this error. 
This is the traceback, can some one please help me what I should look for, for this error?

```
Traceback:
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/ebagu/main/views.py" in index
  63.               post_list = sorted(post_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  162.         self._fetch_all()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "main_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."main_post"."image", "main_post"."thumbnail" FROM "main_post...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @DerekKwok of course, makemigrations, migrate, syncdb are the first things I did

Comment: @winixxee best way to check drop db and try again...

Comment: @RajaSimon how do I dropbdb?

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` and then `python manage.py migrate myapp` ?

Comment: @winixxee it's drop database "yourdb"